# VBA Excel disable printing

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Sheets("Recibo Km A2IT").Range("F20").Value = "Inválido" Or Sheets("Recibo Km A2IT").Range("F31").Value = "Inválido" Or Sheets("Recibo Km A2IT").Range("F42").Value = "Inválido" Or Sheets("Recibo Km A2IT").Range("F53").Value = "Inválido" Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox ("Por favor verifique se os campos estão válidos")
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm trying to implement this on an Excel sheet but can't find out how to make it work. It just doesn't do anything. I want to keep it working all the time because the cells can be "Inválido" or "" but it depends on other conditions.

Can you say what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `If... End If`?

Comment: Yes it works.. so theres something wrong with the if right? I dont know if tahts the proper way to use the if or , im new to vb

Comment: It is the right way. Apparently none of the cells contain the value "Inválido". Maybe something with the "á"? How is "Inválido" added to the cell? via vba or formula or by hand?

Comment: If it is a problem with the character, you could also check for `""` and only proceed if all the cells are empty.

Comment: I already figured it out , thank you guys i opted to make a formula that trigers a result that would return a value and then just single check it on my vba

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this:

```
If (Sheets("Recibo Km A2IT").Range("F20").Value = "Inválido") Or _
    (Sheets("Recibo Km A2IT").Range("F31").Value = "Inválido") Or _
    (Sheets("Recibo Km A2IT").Range("F42").Value = "Inválido") Or _
    (Sheets("Recibo Km A2IT").Range("F53").Value = "Inválido") Then
```

Comment: I already got it right , now i have a problem that might look easy :